# cant output the thumbnail on the screen i get a clean white screen with a little broken image on the top left

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

just white screen not even getting the upload form help heres my code no errors are displayed.

### newt.php

heres my code-

```
<?php 
require_once('includes/config.inc.php'); 
require_once('includes/functions.inc.php');
include("includes/html_codes.php");
session_start();

$username = $_SESSION["username"];

if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] == false) { 
              // If user is already logged in, redirect to main page 
              redirect('lo.php');}
              
            
    
    
    
    
?>

<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $temporary_name=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"images/".$_FILES['file']['name']);
         $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE); 
         $q = mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE users SET image = '".$_FILES['file']['name']."'WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");
         }
         
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <head>
    <title>Profile</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/form.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/register.css"/>


    <body>
    
     <header>
    <?php topBarl(); ?>
    </header>
    
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file">
            <input type="submit" name="submit">
        </form>
<?php 
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
            $q = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q);
            
$width= 275;
$height= 275;
$orig_image = imagecreatefromjpeg("images/".$row['image']);
if (imagesx($orig_image) > imagesy($orig_image)) {
  $y = 0;
  $x = (imagesx($orig_image) - imagesy($orig_image)) / 2;
  $smallestSide = imagesy($orig_image);
}
 else {
  $x = 0;
  $y = (imagesy($orig_image) - imagesx($orig_image)) / 2;
  $smallestSide = imagesx($orig_image);
} 


$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);



Imagecopyresampled($image_p,$orig_image,0,0,$x,$y,$width,$height,$smallestSide,$smallestSide);
header( 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' ); 
imageJPEG($image_p, NULL, 100); 
imagedestroy($image_p); 
imageDestroy($orig_image); 

?>
```

remember no errors are displayed.
thanks in advance.
if i delete the code below the Imagecopyresampled i mean from header to imagedestroy line
i get the upload form only but without deleting anything i get nothing but a small broken image on top left of the page.

Comment: Could you try-catch your sql work and catch an exception if there.

Comment: There are loads of problems with this, it wont work as expected if its all in one file. enable error reporting! your assigning `$_SESSION["username"]` before checking its set or even logged in. your not checking the upload was successful just blindly inserting it if its there, you have sql injections. And your trying to output an image and set content type headers after content has been sent.

Comment: can you rewrite this code properly so that i could understand your point i know this is lot to ask but can u please help me a bit. though i m also using timthumb(in another file) but i dont know that if its right to use it.thanks in advance

Comment: @user3518459 : it runs with : `<a src="your_image_script.php?with_some_vars=perhaps">` ? really ?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two different approaches that you cannot mix:

- output html in the middle of your code
- output an image at the end of your code

You have to choose:

1. You output html. Then you have to save the image as an image and include it in an image tag like 
   `<img src="your_freshly_saved_image.jpg">`
2. You output an image. Then you cannot output anything else in this script and the source of an image in another html / php page would be your script: 
   `<img src="your_image_script.php?with_some_vars=perhaps">`

Comment: Ok, now this looks much better !! with : `<a src="your_image_script.php?with_some_vars=perhaps">` :: **is one that does not get to run!**

Comment: @moskito-x I just came back and saw that... Anyway, a simple typo, I think it is clear what I meant.

Comment: I just wonder how someone, an answer with wrong code, this marked as correct? And not even to point out what he has done to make it work !